# Should new instance created for each request?

Tags: database, servlets, web

I am building using java servlet/jsp. I have a class to handle database connection, but I dont know should I create each instance for each request or one instance for all requests.
For instance:

**Scenario 1**:

```
class HandleDB {
   public static HandleDB getInstance(); // singleton pattern
   public void initConnection();
   public void releaseConnection();
}
```

then,

```
//at the beginning of a request:
HandleDB.getInstance().initConnection();
// handle tasks
// at the end of request
HandleDB.getInstance().releaseConnection();
```

**Scenario 2**:

```
class HandleDB {
   public void initConnection();
   public void releaseConnection();
}

//at the beginning of a request:
HandleDB db = new HandleDB();
db.initConnection();
// handle tasks
// at the end of request
db.releaseConnection();
db = null;
```

Which scenario should be used in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with Scenario 2. The problem with Scenario 1 is that the same `HandleDB` instance will be shared by all requests and could lead to thread safety issues. Keep in mind that requests can be executed in parallel. The standard is to have one connection per thread/request.

Most Web applications use a connection pool (like C3P0 or Apache DBCP) to avoid having to create a new connection for each request. You get a connection from the pool at the beginning of the request and return it to the pool at the end of the request, so other requests can reuse it later.

Comment: yes, we use Apache DBCP for connection pool and I will go for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Listeners [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm)

```
public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{ 

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
                   /// Destroy DB Connection
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
                   /// Create DB Connection
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have batch of tasks you should create database connection only at beginning of first task then after finishing all task  you should release or free db connection

> for your case scenario 1 is applicable.